# Calculate distance between a single atom and other atoms in a pdb file; print issue

Tags: perl, printing

coding newbie here.
After Frankensteining some codes I found from the internet and from some lab mates I have created a script to calculate the distance between a single atom and all other atoms that match a pattern in the line.
Keep in mind that this is a .pdb file.
PDB file in question: http://rapidshare.com/share/7B1847A6F8A249B12B32D85653B140C4
I run the code and get no error messages, but I get no output.  As in my print checks work.  But when do the distance calculation block runs, there is not distance number outputs.

```
#!/use/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict;

#Usage: ./script.pl input > output

#subroutines for calculations

sub distanceAB
{
    my $distance = 0;

    my $Ax = substr($_[0], 30, 8) + 0;
    my $Ay = substr($_[0], 38, 8) + 0;
    my $Az = substr($_[0], 46, 8) + 0;

   my $Bx = substr($_[1], 30, 8) + 0;
   my $By = substr($_[1], 38, 8) + 0;
   my $Bz = substr($_[1], 46, 8) + 0;

    $distance = sqrt(($Ax - $Bx)**2 + ($Ay - $By)**2 + ($Az - $Bz)**2);
    return sprintf("%4.2f", $distance);
}
#open files for calculations and modify distance cutoff for target residues

my $input = $ARGV[0]; 
my $num = 0;
my $ZNline = '';

open my $PDBFILE, '<', $input or die "can't open .pdb '$input':$!";


while (my $pdbline = <$PDBFILE>) {

if ($pdbline =~ m/^ATOM.*(ZN1  LG1)/)
{
    my $ZNline = $pdbline;
    print "$ZNline \n";
}
#find xyz coordinates for other atoms and store in array
if ( $pdbline =~ m/^ATOM.*(OD2 ASP|NE2 HIS)/)
{
    $Atomline = $pdbline;
    $Atomlinearray[$num] = $Atomline;
    $resname = substr($pdbline, 16, 3);
    $resnamearray[$num] = $resname;
    $resnumber = substr($pdbline, 22, 3);
    $resnumberarray[$num] = $resnumber;
    print "$num \n";
    ++$num;
}
}
close $PDBFILE;

    #calculate Zn to each atom distance
    foreach $i (0 .. $#Atomline) {
    my $Zndistance = distanceAB($ZNline, $Atomlinearray[$i]);
    print "$Zndistance \n";
    print "$resnamearray[$i] $resnumberarray[$i] \n";
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Just remove the my:

```
my $Zndistance=distanceAB($ZNline, $Atomline);
if ($Zndistance < 2.5) {
# __^
    print "$Zndistance\n";
```

if you redeclare it, it is unset.

Change also these lines:

```
my @pdblines = <PDBFILE>;
while (<PDBFILE>) {
```

to:

```
while (my $pdblines = <PDBFILE>) {
```

And

```
if (my $pdbline =~ m/....
```

to

```
if ($pdbline =~ m/....
```

**Complete revision:**

```
my $input = $ARGV[0];
my $num = 0;
my $ZNline = '';
open my $PDBFILE, '<', $input or die "can't open .file '$input':$!";
while (my $pdbline = <$PDBFILE>) {
    if ($pdbline =~ m/^ATOM.*(ZN1  LG1)/) {
        $ZNline = $pdbline;
    } 
    #find xyz coordinates for other atoms and store in array
    elsif ($pdbline =~ m/^ATOM.*(OD2 ASP|NE2 HIS)/) {
        my $Atomline = $pdbline;
        my $resname = substr($pdbline, 16, 3);
        my $resnumber = substr($pdbline, 22, 3);
        #calculate Zn to each atom distance
        my $Zndistance = distanceAB($ZNline, $Atomline);
        if ($Zndistance < 2.5) {
            print "$Zndistance\n";
            print "$resname $resnumber \n";
            print "Coordinator $num \n";
        }
    }
    ++$num;
}
```

Comment: I removed the my near $Zndistance=distanceAB($ZNline, $Atomline);
but I still get blank for my output.
I then turned off use strict and got rid some of the "my"s but I still get a blank for my out

Comment: @user3075681: Remove the `my` that is in the `if`.

Comment: Did that, still output is still blank.  I have attached the input file if that helps.  Perhaps it is a formatting issue in my input file?

Comment: I used your suggestion previously and it did not work.  I tried it again anyways after your suggestion and again I got the same 
error:

     Use of uninitialized value $pdbline in pattern match (m//) at ./getRESZNdistance.pl line 40, <PDBFILE> line 1.
can't identify ZN1 line at ./getRESZNdistance.pl line 40, <PDBFILE> line 1.

Comment: Use of uninitialized value in addition (+) at ./getRESZNdistance_2.pl line 15, <$PDBFILE> line 2463.
I got those errors running your code, it seems like there is a problem with how it calls up the coordinates for the non-Zinc atoms.

I also modified, the original code with print checks.  The script outputs the $ZNline and $num, but I still get no prints from my distance calculation block.